# Is the generalized quaternion group $Q_{n}$ isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_{2^{n-1}}$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quaternions, dihedral-groups

this is an exercise in the book ***"Elementos de Álgebra"***, a brazillian book of *Algebra by Arnaldo Garcia and Yves Lequain* (This is not a homework, I'm doing this by myself).

> Let $n \geq 3$ an integer. Show that $Q_{n}$ (the generalized quaternion group) is not isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $2^n$, $D_{2^{n-1}}$.

The book itself say that may be usefull to show that $Q_{n}$ has only one element of order 2. This is actually easy and was already solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011666/a-reference-for-a-generalized-quaternion-group-has-a-unique-element-of-order-2). The question, then is reduced to show that there is two (or more) or none element of order 2 in $D_{2^{n-1}}$.

But we know that every reflection on some line of symmetry in $D_{2^{n-1}}$ has order 2, so, as we have $n \geq 3$, there are at least 2 reflections for each $n$.

So, $Q_{n}$ cannot be isomorphic to  $D_{2^{n-1}}$; (Isomorphism preserves order).

Am I right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yeah, this is right. This is one of the main strategies to proving that two strange groups are not isomorphic. (ie. they admit different subgroup lattices)