# Existence of an involution in generalized quaternions group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

For $n \ge 3$, let
$$ Q = \langle x,y \mid x^{2^{n-1}}=e, yxy^{-1} = x^{-1}, x^{2^{n-2}} = y^2 \rangle $$
be the generalized quaternions group.

I want to show that $Q$ has a unique involution using the presentation.

I know that it may be $x$ or $y$ because the only involution in the quaternions (which is $-1$) also lies in the center.
In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011666/a-reference-for-a-generalized-quaternion-group-has-a-unique-element-of-order-2) question it's said that pretty easy but I don't see how to start.

Any hints?

Comment: Well, $$(y^2)^2=\left(x^{2^{n-2}}\right)^2=x^{2^{n-1}}=e$$ for a start . . .

Comment: @Shaun For this step it's ok but how can show that it's the only one ?

Comment: I would use the fact  that $x$ generates an index two subgroup $H$ of order $2^{n-1}$ and $Q=H\cap yH$. So every element is either of the form $x^j$ or of the form $yx^j$. Check the elements of the latter type. $H$ is clear, because it is cyclic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean $n\geq 3$, not $n\leq 3$...

Comment: The main thing is proving that $x$ has order exactly $2^{n-1}$; it is easy to show it has order at least $2^{n-2}$ (map to the dihedral group of order $2^{n-1}$).  Once you know that, you can use Jyrki’s suggestion to show that none of the elements of the form $yx^i$ are involutions.